# Display Directories with a Bold Font – How to enable? with .bash_profile?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm using a linux server that display directories in a bold font, and files in a normal font.

---

e.g. `$ ls` produces

afile.txt   **afolder**   anotherfile.txt    **anotherfolder**

---

I'd like to use this feature on some other servers. How can it be done? with the .bash_profile?

If anyone has other ideas on how to differentiate folders from file, they'd be good to know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to give `ls` the `--colors=…` option (e.g. via an alias). To actually configure the `LS_COLORS` environmental variable used to define the colours, one good way is to create a configuration file for `dircolors`, e.g. with just bold (attribute 1) directories:

```
echo DIR 1 >~/.dir_colors
```

Then in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`, `eval` the output of `dircolors` run on that file to set `LS_COLORS` according to your configuration. The relevant lines in my `.bashrc` (copied from somewhere) look like this:

```
  if [ -n "$COLORTERM" ]; then
      alias ls='ls -F --color=auto'
      if [ -x "`which dircolors`" -a -r "$HOME/.dir_colors" ]; then
          eval `dircolors -b "$HOME/.dir_colors"`
      fi
  else
      alias ls='ls -F'
  fi
```

Note that some terminals do not, by default, display the bold attribute as true bold but rather just use a brighter colour. You need to configure your terminal to get real bold.

See the `dircolors --print-database` for an example of a “complete” configuration file.

Comment: Not cool. I like that tip a lot.
Here's an upvote 5 years and a half later.

Answer (score 2):

add this to your .bashrc or .profile: alias ls='ls --color=auto'

Answer (score 2):

> If anyone has other ideas on how to differentiate folders from file, they'd be good to know?

`ls` does have the ability to differentiate items using the `-F` flag.

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html):

```
-F, --classify
          append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
```

All you have to do is add `-F` to your `ls` command in your terminal like so:

```
$ ls -F
```

You can make this permanent by setting up an alias by opening your `.bashrc` (or similar) file and adding:

`alias ls='ls -F'`

After setting that (and either logging out and back on or running `source ~/.bashrc`), you can simply run `ls` and it will always assume you added `-F`.

Answer (score 1):

See the man page for ls, the -F option as was said above gives you probably what you need to readily see which names are folders, executables and symbolic links. And see the -G option to color the files you can also use both. I guess it's so simple, I wouldn't bother to put it in an alias. You can also use both to get the two effects at the same time.

```
ls -F -G

ls -FG
```

Answer (score 0):

It's done with an environment variable.  Start with reading the ls man page:

```
$ man ls
```

You may not be able to get just bold, but only bold with a specific color.